# How to use where clause only once for multiple subqueries in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, correlated-subquery

I have a query where I am joining together multiple aggregate subqueries...

```
SELECT productionDate, shift, productID, workerID, infeedweight, outfeedweight, ...
FROM generalTable

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT productionDate, shift, productID, workerID, sum(weight) as infeedweight
        FROM infeed
#       WHERE productionDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-07'
        GROUP BY productionDate, shift, productID, workerID)
    t1 USING (productionDate, shift, productID, workerID)

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT productionDate, shift, productID, workerID, sum(weight) as outfeedweight
        FROM outfeed
#       WHERE productionDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-07'
        GROUP BY productionDate, shift, productID, workerID)
    t2 USING (productionDate, shift, productID, workerID)

    ... 

    etc

WHERE productionDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-07'
```

If I run this with the indicated WHERE statements commented out (but not the top-level WHERE), it takes 11 seconds.  With the WHERE statements uncommented, it takes 0.1 seconds.  The result is exactly the same.

Is there a way to (possibly with a optimizer hint or something) get the query to use the top-level WHERE clause in all of the subqueries instead of having to repeat it everywhere?

The reporting software I am using only seems to be designed to put one WHERE clause at the end of the SQL statement, so if it isn't possible I will probably have to do some ugly hack to make it work.

Also, the reporting software will be filtering on shift, productID, and workerID as well as productionDate.

EDIT: changed error in SQL tables

Comment: Other than a single field alias, those subqueries are identical with or without the WHERE clauses. Is that a pasting error? _And no, WHERE's are (mostly) processed after JOIN's at the same query level, and subqueries (barring correlated subqueries) must be processed before being JOINed._ You could put correlated subqueries in the SELECT portion, but it would definitely be a lot slower than subqueries with WHERE clauses; and probably even slower than the single WHERE clause version you attempted.

Comment: Uueerdo... I edited to update.  It should be aggregations on different tables.